# Show class name in Intellij's CLion Structure panel

Tags: c++, clion

I'm using Intellij CLion to browse some source code, and there's a `cpp` file with the definition of two classes. Given both classes inherit from the same base class, they have methods with the same name, but in the structure panel they cannot be discerned:

[image: Structure panel]

Is there a way of prefixing each method with the class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: No, it is not possible to show the class name in structure view for `cpp` files.

According to [this open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1703), the tree view is available for header files only.

Answer (score 0):

now you can use ALT+7 to show it,and my Clion's version is 2021.1

Comment: `Alt+7` just toggles the `Structure` view. It doesn't show class name for the functions listed in the view.